# What does the following algorithm approximate? (Assume m>1,ϵ>0)

Tags: algorithm

```
x = m;
y = 1;
While (x-y > ϵ)
{
    x = (x+y)/2;
    y = m/x;
}
print(x);
```

Answer is \sqrt{m}

I don't know how to reach that conclusion because i don't know the value of ϵ, I have tried but i result in bunch of equations which doesn't make sense to me.

Please help me to understand how to understand and breakdown this type of questions
Thank you

Comment: It's an implementation of the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method). ϵ is a constant that determines the amount of precision you get.

Comment: It also corresponds to the resolution of the system `y = x^2 - m = 0` by the Newton method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say maybe pick a language, implement your algorithm, then print things out, you would see how the algorithm performs the task step by step:

For instance in Python, your algorithm would probably look like:

```
ϵ = 10
m = 30
x = m
y = 1

while x - y > ϵ:
    x = (x + y) // 2
    y = m // x

print(x)
```

If we would print the variables of the algorithm, wherever you want to and step by step, you'd observe how the algorithm works:

```
ϵ = 4
m = 90
x = m
y = 1

step = 0
while x - y > ϵ:
    step += 1
    print(f'-----------------step {step}----------------')
    print(f'x before first operation is {x}')
    print(f'y before first operation is {y}')
    print(f'ϵ before first operation is {ϵ}')
    print(f'x - y before first operation is {x - y}')
    print(f'm before first operation is {m}')
    x = (x + y) // 2

    print(f'x after first operation is {x}')
    print(f'y after first operation is {y}')
    print(f'ϵ after first operation is {ϵ}')
    print(f'x - y after first operation is {x - y}')
    print(f'm after first operation is {m}')

    y = m // x

    print(f'x after second operation is {x}')
    print(f'y after second operation is {y}')
    print(f'ϵ after second operation is {ϵ}')
    print(f'x - y after second operation is {x - y}')
    print(f'm after second operation is {m}')

print(x)
```

#### Output

```
-----------------step 1----------------
x before first operation is 90
y before first operation is 1
ϵ before first operation is 4
x - y before first operation is 89
m before first operation is 90
x after first operation is 45
y after first operation is 1
ϵ after first operation is 4
x - y after first operation is 44
m after first operation is 90
x after second operation is 45
y after second operation is 2
ϵ after second operation is 4
x - y after second operation is 43
m after second operation is 90
-----------------step 2----------------
x before first operation is 45
y before first operation is 2
ϵ before first operation is 4
x - y before first operation is 43
m before first operation is 90
x after first operation is 23
y after first operation is 2
ϵ after first operation is 4
x - y after first operation is 21
m after first operation is 90
x after second operation is 23
y after second operation is 3
ϵ after second operation is 4
x - y after second operation is 20
m after second operation is 90
-----------------step 3----------------
x before first operation is 23
y before first operation is 3
ϵ before first operation is 4
x - y before first operation is 20
m before first operation is 90
x after first operation is 13
y after first operation is 3
ϵ after first operation is 4
x - y after first operation is 10
m after first operation is 90
x after second operation is 13
y after second operation is 6
ϵ after second operation is 4
x - y after second operation is 7
m after second operation is 90
-----------------step 4----------------
x before first operation is 13
y before first operation is 6
ϵ before first operation is 4
x - y before first operation is 7
m before first operation is 90
x after first operation is 9
y after first operation is 6
ϵ after first operation is 4
x - y after first operation is 3
m after first operation is 90
x after second operation is 9
y after second operation is 10
ϵ after second operation is 4
x - y after second operation is -1
m after second operation is 90
9
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62078168/6553328) also explains it simple.

Answer (score 2):

Note that:

- the loop will continue until x and y are within ϵ of each other;
- y = m / x  ⇒ y * x = m at each iteration.

When the stopping condition is met we know that x * (x - ϵ) = x<sup>2</sup> - ϵx = m.  Consequently, as ϵ → 0, that means x<sup>2</sup> → m, so x (and y) must converge to sqrt(m). ϵ is the tolerance you specify for that convergence.